# python static class with static method that uses self?

Tags: python, class, static, static-methods

I'm doing a database insert script in pycassa. I want to set up a public static class that defines some variables that will get used a lot by other functions later on. Heres what I have...

```
class ks_refs():
    pool = ConnectionPool('TweetsKS')

    user_name_cf = self.cf_connect('UserName')
    user_tweet_cf = self.cf_connect('UserTweet')

    def cf_connect(column_family):
        cf = pycassa.ColumnFamily(self.pool, column_family)
        return cf
```

I haven't even tried to run this yet because I'm sure it wont work. You can see I want this static variable 'pool' first, and then set up user_name_cf and user_tweet_cf (and some more later) using the cf_connect method which needs 'pool' to work.

I know I could put that method outside the class, or I could have this non-static and make an instance of it, but I want to try this because this is what I really want (before I was just using globals but I think a static class holding all this is the best idea)

Comment: I think by `static method` you mean a `class method` (Python isn't C++). However it seems to me that doing this is nothing more than the wrapping of a bunch stuff into a namespace, is is fine unto itself, but it's not much better than just using global variables which is generally considered a bad programming practice.

Comment: cheers! and yes I am more familiar with this type of stuff in C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to have a *class* method instead:

```
@classmethod
def cf_connect(cls, column_family):
    cf = pycassa.ColumnFamily(cls.pool, column_family)
    return cf
```

Now you can refer to the pool defined on your class with ease.

Your `user_name_cf` and `user_tweet_cf` 'attributes' will not work, however. You can add these after having created the class definition:

```
class ks_refs():
    pool = ConnectionPool('TweetsKS')

    @classmethod
    def cf_connect(cls, column_family):
        cf = pycassa.ColumnFamily(cls.pool, column_family)
        return cf

user_name_cf = ks_refs.cf_connect('UserName')
user_tweet_cf = ks_refs.cf_connect('UserTweet')
```

where they are then module-level constants, or you can add them to the class as attributes after the fact:

```
ks_refs.user_name_cf = ks_refs.cf_connect('UserName')
ks_refs.user_tweet_cf = ks_refs.cf_connect('UserTweet')
```